# How can I echo taskwarrior output to a file without truncation?

Tags: taskwarrior

Whenever I run the following:

```
task due.before:tom or schedule.before:tom > somefile
```

The content of `somefile` is always truncated. But running this without the redirect, it works fine.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What's wrong with `somefile` being truncated? What would you want to happen instead? Please clarify this [in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/673508/edit)

Comment: @roaima When I run taskwarrior in my terminal, I get a list of my tasks. When I redirect this output to a file, I get a truncated list of tasks in the file. What's not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
task limit:none
```

works shows me an untruncated list of the tasks of my otherwise truncated default report.

```
task help | grep limit
```

says

```
limit:          Desired number of rows in report, or 'page'
```

BTW, there also is

```
task information
```

which shows all fields (even those that are not viewable as columns according to $task columns. I use this to view Annotations which don't seem to go into a column in table view.

there once was

```
report.*.limit
```

according to https://github.com/GothenburgBitFactory/taskwarrior/blob/e13c479ab23851696f2261a360e9c0ff1d4f217f/src/legacy.cpp#L97
but it was deprecated.